# Converting rows to row groups

Tags: scripting

Can somebody please help me with the below conversion shell script ?

Source File File 1 :  for example

```
EXCHANGE_ID     :  192,                       410,
EXCHANGE_DTTM   :  2015-06-11+02:18:40+0000,        2015-06-11+02:12:28+0000,
PART_NAME       :  MRT,                     LR04,
PART_TRANS_ID   :  123,                       JAS04,
M_NAME      :  FAILED,  FAILED,
M_DTTM      :  2015-06-11T02:18:40+0000      2015-06-11T02:12:28+0000
```

OutPut  as :

```
EXCHANGE _ID    :  192
EXCHANGE_ DTTM  :  2015-06-11T02:18:40+0000
PART_NAME       :  MRT
PART_TRANS_ID   :  123
M_NAME          :  FAILED
M _DTTM         :  2015-06-11T02:18:40+0000

EXCHANGE _ID    :  410
EXCHANGE_DTTM   :  2015-06-11T02:12:28+0000
PART_NAME       :  LR04
PART_TRANS_ID   :  JAS04
M_NAME          :  FAILED
M_DTTM          :  2015-06-11T02:12:28+0000
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) f[i] = f[i] " " $i ; if (NF > n) n = NF } END { for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) sub(/^ */, "", f[i]) ; for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) print f[i] } ' FAILED.csv > TGT_FAILED.out
```

but that just prints things out a CSV instead of the desired format.  Here's an example of the actual output, as opposed to the desired output from above:

```
EXCHANGE_ID EXCHANGE_DTTM PART_NAME PART_TRANS_ID M_NAME M_DTTM
: : : : : :
192, 2015-06-11+02:18:40+0000, MRT, 123, FAILED, 2015-06-11T02:18:40+0000
410, 2015-06-11+02:12:28+0000, LR04, JAS04, FAILED, 2015-06-11T02:12:28+0000
```

Comment: Tried few awk option but nothing worked for me ... really apprecate a quick response.... Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and what about it wasn't working for you?

Comment: awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) f[i] = f[i] " " $i ;
       if (NF > n) n = NF }
 END { for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) sub(/^  */, "", f[i]) ;
       for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) print f[i] }
    ' FAILED.csv  > TGT_FAILED.out

Comment: I know my script is not giving me the right output. Can you help me with correct script to get the desired output ?

Comment: Does your *Source File 1*  have more fields ? If so how many approximately.  Also does *Source File 1* have more repeating line groups like the 6 lines shown, and if so are they delimited by a blank line or suchlike?

Comment: Source file does not have any more feilds ... and this is how exactly the file looks...

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
awk -F'[ \t,]+' '{a=a$1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\n"; b=b$1"\t"$2"\t"$4"\n"} END {print a; print b}' data.txt
```

Here we treat one or more space, tab, or comma as a field separator. Then on each line we build the output. Finally we print the results. This is a pretty dirty one liner; for example it has to read the whole file before it prints anything so for large files it's going to be bad on memory, but for smallish files it should do the trick.

From your input, this should result in:

```
EXCHANGE_ID :   192
EXCHANGE_DTTM   :   2015-06-11+02:18:40+0000
PART_NAME   :   MRT
PART_TRANS_ID   :   123
M_NAME  :   FAILED
M_DTTM  :   2015-06-11T02:18:40+0000

EXCHANGE_ID :   410
EXCHANGE_DTTM   :   2015-06-11+02:12:28+0000
PART_NAME   :   LR04
PART_TRANS_ID   :   JAS04
M_NAME  :   FAILED
M_DTTM  :   2015-06-11T02:12:28+0000
```

If you want the fields to be nicely spaced you can add sprintf to the call like this:

```
awk -F'[ \t,]+' '{label=sprintf("'%-10s'",$1); a=a""label"\t"$2"  "$3"\n"; b=b""label"\t"$2"  "$4"\n"} END {print a; print b}' data.txt
```

This gives the prettier output of:

```
EXCHANGE_ID     :  192
EXCHANGE_DTTM   :  2015-06-11+02:18:40+0000
PART_NAME       :  MRT
PART_TRANS_ID   :  123
M_NAME          :  FAILED
M_DTTM          :  2015-06-11T02:18:40+0000

EXCHANGE_ID     :  410
EXCHANGE_DTTM   :  2015-06-11+02:12:28+0000
PART_NAME       :  LR04
PART_TRANS_ID   :  JAS04
M_NAME          :  FAILED
M_DTTM          :  2015-06-11T02:12:28+0000
```

Comment: Thanks alot for you response but still not getting the desired output .... :(

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: Note that your output is a little inconsistent. For example, `EXCHANGE_ID` has a space before the `_` and `DTTM` has one before but only in the first case. I'm guessing the field names are contiguous and that's just a typo.

Comment: Those are just the typo all am trying to acheive is ...

Comment: if col1 col2 col3
 a b c
 1 2 3
 x y z
 
 or
 
if col1 a,1,x
 col2 b,2,y
 col3 c,3,z
 
 
Required Output is 

Col1 : a
Col2 : b
Col3 : c

Col1 : 1
Col2 : 2 
Col3 : 3

Col1 : x
Col2 : y
Col3 : x

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

To handle an input file with just *1 group* of 6 lines and just *2 data* columns, a simple –but limited, and greedy on resources– approach makes the coding overhead minimal, ie, no need for *arrays* to hold data from all 6 line:

```
f='src.txt'       # input fule
d=' +: +| +|, *'  # field delimiter regex
set {2,3}         # data columns - not label (which is column 1)
for c; do paste \
   <(gawk -F"$d" '1,6{print $1"\t:"}' "$f") \
   <(gawk -F"$d" '1,6{print $c}' c=$c "$f") |
     column -t; echo; done
```

---

The following `awk` method handles unlimited repeating 6-line groups, and any number of fields per line.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=" +: +|, +|,| +"; OFS="\t"; maxw=length("EXCHANGE_DTTM") }
     /^EXCHANGE_ID/,/^M_DTTM/{ rn++
       if($NF=="") NF--
       for(fn=1;fn<=NF;fn++) cell[rn"."fn]=$fn
       if(rn==6){
         for(fn=2;fn<=NF;fn++) 
           for(rn=1;rn<=6;rn++)
             printf("%-"maxw"s : %s\n"(rn==6?"\n":""), cell[rn"."1], cell[rn"."fn]) 
         rn=0 }}' <"$f"
```

Output:

```
EXCHANGE_ID   : 192
EXCHANGE_DTTM : 2015-06-11+02:18:40+0000
PART_NAME     : MRT
PART_TRANS_ID : 123
M_NAME        : FAILED
M_DTTM        : 2015-06-11T02:18:40+0000

EXCHANGE_ID   : 410
EXCHANGE_DTTM : 2015-06-11+02:12:28+0000
PART_NAME     : LR04
PART_TRANS_ID : JAS04
M_NAME        : FAILED
M_DTTM        : 2015-06-11T02:12:28+0000
```

---

Here is a `bash` version of the `awk` script above. The logic flow is the same. I've added some error checking and blank-line skipping.

```
set EXCHANGE_DTTM; maxw=${#1}; nl=0    # length of longest label; line number
set -f; declare -A cell; cm=" "; nf=0  # no-globbing; cells-array; cell-margin; number-of-fields 
while IFS= read -r line; do ((nl+=1))  # increment line number
  [[ $line =~ ^[[:blank:]]*$ ]] && continue            # skip blank/empty lines 
  [[ $line =~ ^EXCHANGE_ID\ * ]] && rn=1 || ((rn+=1))  # reset/increment record number
  IFS=" ,"; f=(${line/ : / }); IFS=; f=(${f[@]})       # split line into fields
  (( nf )) && (( nf!=${#f[@]} )) && { echo ERROR: field count is not consistent; exit 1; } || nf=${#f[@]} 
  for (( fn=0; fn<nf; fn++ ));do cell[$rn.$fn]="${f[$fn]}"; done  # build cells-array
  (( rn==6 )) && {
    [[ $line =~ ^M_DTTM\ .* ]] || { echo ERROR: unexpected label found - record $rn$'\n'"$line"; exit 2; }
    for (( fn=1; fn<nf; fn++ )) ;do
      for (( rn=1; rn<=6; rn++ )) ;do
        (( rn==6 )) && b=$"\n" || b=""
        printf "%-${maxw}s${cm}:${cm}%s\n$b" "${cell[$rn.0]}" "${cell[$rn.$fn]}"
        done; done; } done <"$f"
```

Comment: awk '{print $1 ,": "  $3}' Src.txt | column -t
awk '{for(x=2;$x;++x) print $1, $x "\n"}'  Src.txt | column -t

Comment: @arsh: I'm not sure what the point of your comment is.  It seems you have 2  `awk | column` snippets, neither of which deal with the delimiters properly. Aside from the problem of delimiters. The first one deals with only the first *data column*. The second one's output is in the wrong 'orientation' - thoughe each output block is *row-based*, as per the input, each *column* needs to be precessed individually (in blocks of 6 rows). – What I wanted from my answer, was to *not* use `column`, and to be able to handle any number of *data columns*, and any number of  *6-row-blocks* of data.

Comment: the only reason am using the column -t is for proper indenting ... but am not able achieve the orientation of column names and data values ...

Comment: By *proper* indenting do you mean a *margin* of  of 2 spaces on both sides of the `:` as in your output sample? - My script uses amargin of 1 space on both sides of `:`, but that is *very* easy to change.

Comment: awk '{for(x=2;$x;++x) print $1, $x "\n"}'  Src.txt  Can you help me with proper looping for this command ?

Comment: @arsh: *Looping* is not the primary issue. The main thing is that you need to *store* the relevant data from ***all*** 6 lines, before you can start  the *looping* ... arrays are the way to do it.  refer to my code above where I store each ***cell*** in an array (awk's version of a 2-dimensional array), and then when all 6 lines have been read, the *looping* processing begins: see `for(fn=2;fn<=NF;fn++)` and ` for(rn=1;rn<=6;rn++)`

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet considered how usefully `sed` might be applied to your data, please, allow me to demonstrate:

```sh
sed '    s/\([^, ]\{1,\}\),*/\1,/2                                                                                 
         s//\1/3;H;y/,/\n/;P;/^M_D.*/!d
         s///;x;s/[^, ]*, *//g
'        <<\IN
EXCHANGE_ID:  192,                       410,
EXCHANGE_DTTM:  2015-06-11+02:18:40+0000,        2015-06-11+02:12:28+0000,
PART_NAME:  MRT,                     LR04,
PART_TRANS_ID:  123,                       JAS04,
M_NAME:  FAILED,  FAILED,
M_DTTM:  2015-06-11T02:18:40+0000      2015-06-11T02:12:28+000
IN
```

So, the first go round we `P`rint only up to the first occurring comma - and that would be far more simple still if all of the fields were comma-delimited. But they're not, and so about half of the work there is spent ensuring they are.

Anyway, we print only the header and first following sequence of not space characters. Next, we append a copy of the current line to `H`old space, then `d`elete it - *unless* it matches `^M_D`. In that case we e`x`change hold and pattern spaces, then with a single `s///`ubstitution simultaneously remove the second not space sequence of characters and all following spaces from every line we have just saved.

The result is printed to stdout:

```
EXCHANGE_ID:  192
EXCHANGE_DTTM:  2015-06-11+02:18:40+0000
PART_NAME:  MRT
PART_TRANS_ID:  123
M_NAME:  FAILED
M_DTTM:  2015-06-11T02:18:40+0000

EXCHANGE_ID:  410
EXCHANGE_DTTM:  2015-06-11+02:12:28+0000
PART_NAME:  LR04
PART_TRANS_ID:  JAS04
M_NAME:  FAILED
M_DTTM:  2015-06-11T02:12:28+000
```